# Realm handling two transactions on background thread

Tags: android, realm

I have a large set of data, that I need to do some optimilization upon. The background thread looks like this:

```
Realm realm;
try{
 realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
 realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
           //delete some data from table A according to algorithm
        }
    });
} finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
}
```

While at the same time the user can delete the whole table A, if he decides to, before the optimization finishes, which starts another background thread, just like the one above deleting the whole table A.

I would like to know what happens, if one transaction gets finished before the other, do I need to ensure that only one of these transaction happens at a given time?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first transaction will cause the second transaction to be blocked until the first transaction is either committed or cancelled.

Write transactions are blocking across threads and processes.

Comment: Thank you, I have verified by some logging and using Thread.sleep. I will have to cut the long processing function into several transactions, so it would not block the app for too long and give a chance for user to stop/delete the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior. Only one transaction will happen at a time .When you are in a transaction it's blocking and no other thread can perform other transaction.

Basically, you can't start multiple transaction while you are already in a transaction. It will throw an Exception [Check this Link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3753) .

Comment: You can start a transaction on different threads even if there is already write transaction in progress on another thread

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **executeTransactionAsync** instead of **executeTransaction**, the process will be treated in a background thread. Don't be worry about the transaction end, realm manage that for us

Comment: If you're on a background thread, then there is no reason to use executeTransactionAsync

Comment: Maybe it's because is not aware about **Async** method

Comment: nah, I've always done my Realm stuff with download on background thread with `call.execute()` then `realm.executeTransaction()`